# Mysql return record with mistakes - agregation function MAX()

Tags: mysql, linux

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.60, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3

I have one table "mytable" with 12500 records and with this fields

- mytable_id(PRI, auto_increment)
- x_id(integer)
- y_id(integer)
- fieldX(varchar)
- fieldY(varchar).

When execute the consult:

```
select max(x_id), y_id, fieldX, fieldY 
from mytable;
```

and return for example

```
x_id  | y_id | fieldX | fieldY
12121 | 111  | textX  | testY
```

but when execute:

```
select  y_id, fieldX, fieldY 
from mytable 
where x_id = 12121;
```

return

```
y_id | fieldX | fieldY
232  | textX  | textY
```

y_id not matches.

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the last row instead you should do

```
 SELECT *
 FROM mytable
 ORDER BY x_id DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

The problem with your query is you are selecting the MAX value from a field but the other are random values and not necessary related to the row where that Max Value is.

Answer (score 1):

the use of aggregation function without group by can produce unpredictable result for column not involved  in aggregation function and not mentioned  in group by  ..

you could use or aggregation function or order by

```
  select max(x_id), max(y_id), max(fieldX), max(fieldY) 
  from mytable;

  select max(x_id), y_id, fieldX, fieldY 
  from mytable
  group by y_id, fieldX, fieldY ;
```